# How can I access Box.com Comments using API

Tags: box-api, box

I am trying to using Box API to get comments that have been made on the files and folders.

I have tried looking at the box content api but could not find anything useful. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you find any way to fetch comment on file or folder?If yes, then will you please explain the way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

AS is usually the case it turns out I was not digging real deeply into the documentation.

Here is the link to the documentation for accessing comments in the box.com api.

https://developers.box.com/docs/#comments

The link explains it really well. I cant really think of copying and pasting it here since I wont be adding anything. The key concept in box.com api is the authentication and after that one can simply pass parameters for file_id and then post and go to /comments url and get the response. Then comes the sifting of comments which can also be done using the api.